# HTML Required tag does not respond with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to let the user fill a form.

When the user has filled the form correctly the logo on the webpage changes and the data of the form gets posted to the PHP page where it is being send to the database.

I have trouble with the "required" attribute working with the Jquery code for the submit button because the attribute does not show up when I hook up any Jquery code.

Is there a way to let the original functionality of the "required" attribute to work with the Jquery code I provided below while staying on the same page?

```
<form class="center" action="" method="post" id="form">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="width: 175px" required>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 175px" required>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="telephone" style="width: 175px" required>
   <br>
   <br>
   <select style="width: 175px" id="name" name='city' required>
      <option value='null' selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
      <option value='option1'>option1</option>
      <option value='option2'>option2</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" style="width: 175px">
</form>
```

---

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
   $("#image").attr("src", "2.png");
   $.post("sender.php", {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
      telephone: $('#telephone').val(),
      city: $('#city').val()
   });
});
```

Comment: You can't rely on html5 validation, older browsers do not support it. Use javascript to validate your form.

Comment: you should not rely on html5 validation to much, you should use a javascript to validate the form.
I suggest Jquery Validation Plugin:http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventdefault()`in jquery. preventdefault will stop default action(submitting the form) and then you can write your code to validate and display error.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
   event.preventdefault();
// call some function to validate & display error.
   $("#image").attr("src", "2.png");
   $.post("sender.php", {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
      telephone: $('#telephone').val(),
      city: $('#city').val()
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one :-

```
$("#form").validate({
                submitHandler : function() {
//Your Code
});
```

User jquery validation for working in all browser